# php var with multiple assoc arrays, get values one array at a time

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop, associative-array

Originally I was taking an uploaded .csv file and iterating through the values one row at a time.. with the below `while` loop.

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     var_dump($data);
     $importIt = $repo->impThreeCSV($which, $data);
 }
```

I have redone the .csv upload functionality to now be a web form where I send json to the PHP file on a 'save button'. I now have a variable with multiple associative arrays in it..

```
    $fd = json_decode($df, true);
    var_dump($fd);
```

For instance the dump above contains multiple arrays such as below: i.e. (~300 similar arrays as below).

```
array (size=806)
  0 => 
    array (size=18)
      'ATM_ID' => string 'AFF-MIL-TWR' (length=11)
      'FAC_IDENT' => string 'AFF' (length=3)
      'LG_NAME' => string 'BLACH BLAH ACADEMY' (length=20)
      'BASIC_TP' => string 'MIL-TWR' (length=7)
      .................
```

- How can I iterate through the *VALUES* only in these arrays, one at a
  time in the same fashion as my original `while` loop.. (this would be
  ideal so I don't have to redo the whole back-end).
- I am having issues handling the multiple arrays and getting the
  values only out..
- I have tried the below two attempts, I just get 'arrayarrayarray' or
  similar in `var_dump`. Do I need to break out each array into it's
  own var? What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to run a count on how
  many arrays consist in my var?

  ```
   $fd = json_decode($df, true);
   var_dump($fd);

   $data = array_values($fd);
   foreach ($data as $array_key) {
       echo $array_key;
   }

   $array_keys = array_keys($fd);
       foreach ($array_keys as $array_key) {
       echo $array_key;
   }
  ```

P.S. No, I can't use pandas, I wish.

Comment: Just to be sure, taking the dump containing multiple arrays as an example, the foreach you want would get 'AFF-MIL-TWR', then 'AFF', etc doing all arrays in one loop as if they all were in the same array ?

Comment: No, ideally treating each array as a ‘row’ such as my original while loop with csv data

Comment: Each array is a row of data I’m importing into a database..

Comment: Ah, it's easy then, foreach inside foreach. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard it looks he deleted it..

Comment: I guess he did this to not "steal" an answer, which is nice ! Added the answer then :) Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to process the data in the same way as your original piece of code, you would just use something like:

```
foreach ($fd as $data) {
    $importIt = $repo->impThreeCSV($which, array_values($data));
}
```

Note I've used [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to convert `$data` from an associative array to a numerically indexed one, i.e. the same format as `fgetcsv` returns. This may - dependent on your `$repo->impThreeCSV` code - not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a foreach to loop through each array, and then do another foreach to loop through every value of the array you're looping through.

```
$decodedJson = [
    [
        'ATM_ID' => 'AFF-MIL-TWR 1',
        'FAC_IDENT' => 'AFF',
        'LG_NAME' => 'BLACH BLAH ACADEMY',
        'BASIC_TP' => 'MIL-TWR',
    ],
    [
        'ATM_ID' => 'AFF-MIL-TWR 2',
        'FAC_IDENT' => 'AFF',
        'LG_NAME' => 'BLACH BLAH ACADEMY',
        'BASIC_TP' => 'MIL-TWR',
    ],
];

foreach ($decodedJson as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        print $item; # => AFF-MIL-TWR 1
    }
}
```